# How do I hide something when the user zooms into a UIScrollView, then show it when they zoom out?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

When the user zooms into my UIScrollView, I want to hide extraneous information. Right now, I'm handling that in the `scrollViewDidZoom` delegate method that gets called on every zoom change:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.zoomScale > scrollView.minimumZoomScale) {
        [self hideExtraInformation:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self hideExtraInformation:NO];
    }
```

My problem is that in that `hideExtraInformation:` method, the hiding is animating the alpha out. As this is called on every zoom change, the animation is being triggered a ton. How do I make it so the animation is only called on initial zoom in, and then when they get back to being zoomed out completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `currentZoomScale` property to your class and use this to determine if the work is required

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  BOOL isZooming         = scrollView.zoomScale  > scrollView.minimumZoomScale;
  BOOL isCurrentlyZoomed = self.currentZoomScale > scrollView.minimumZoomScale;

  if (isCurrentlyZoomed) {
    if (!isZooming) {
      [self hideExtraInformation:NO];
    }
  } else {
    if (isZooming) {
      [self hideExtraInformation:YES];
    }
  }

  self.currentZoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale;
}
```

Comment: Would be easier to store a visibility state. ;-)